# The code within the method 'InitializeComponent' is generated by the designer and should not be manually modified.

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, winforms, c#-4.0

I am getting this error when i open the design of a Winform.

**Message   1244    The designer cannot process the code at line 108: 
this.cancelButton.DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel;
The code within the method 'InitializeComponent' is generated by the designer and should not be manually modified.  Please remove any changes and try opening the designer again.**

But when either i remove this piece of code from the designer.cs or change it to

this.cancelButton.DialogResult = System.windows.Forms.DialogResult.Cancel;

it works. My problem is i have this problem at almost all the winforms over a solution at many places. How can i resolve this issue to all places? Any way?

Comment: The code within the method 'InitializeComponent' is generated by the designer and should not be manually modified. You need to remove any chnages to this method from all the places where they are present. That is if you want these form to be opened in the designer.

Comment: you should follow @zespri's advice. a dirty method try to add `using System.windows.Forms;` to the `Designer.cs` file

Comment: Is there no any other way to resolve this issue? as this is at many places over the solution. i have already used the system.windows.forms at every form's designer.cs.

Comment: @user1487911 take a look at my solution, it's another recommended way to fix the stuff.

Answer (score 4):

Advice from @zespri and @bansi are some good pieces, but you are suggested to do all customized construct time design in your **constructor**, after `InitializeComponent()`.

Comment: Hi I have the same problem... I didnt understand your solution could you explain a bit ?

Comment: the OP encountered the problem because designer.cs doesn't have `using System.windows.Forms`, so the designer won't be compiled and thus failed the rendering. A better way is to put all customized code into form's constructor, so the designer compilation and rendering won't fail even if some of your initialization logic go wrong (which definitely will fail when you run the program).

Comment: so what you suggest is that i need to put my public class file(eg: mycombobox cutom code) inside the constructor of each form.cs class file to avoid this issue  ?

Comment: when i try the above process its showing different errors related to delegates.